# MongoDB connection with Power BI

Tags: mongodb, nosql, powerbi, odbc, business-intelligence

I have this mongoDB (a SaSS in IBM Cloud) and on this cloud i also have an instance of another noSQL DB, cloudant db.

We were able to connect the cloudant DB on Power BI using only an URL such as "https://8869f932-05f0-4f48-b697-XXXXXXXXXXXX-bluemix.cloudantnosqldb.appdomain.cloud/<DATABASE_NAME>/_design/<DESIGN_DOC_NAME>/_view/<VIEW_NAME>" and "WEB" connection option on PowerBI.

My question is, and i didn't find any info or documentation related to this matter: on MongoDB, there is a way to achieve this kind of connection, using only a uri to a specific view rather than the ODBC connection?

If not, is there any other alternative to connect with this resource on IBM instead of ODBC?

Answer (score 0):

1. Install mongosqld from : https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/current/installation/
2. Run mongosqld
3. Now you can connect to the mongodb instance with read access using mysql/mariadb client or drivers.

**NOTE**: As mentioned this only has read access, so you can execute all the select queries.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the main goal of using a URI connection such as we do with CloudantDB is to don't need to ratify new softwares inside the company (we'll have this big burocracy and delay just to add this connector on the company software white list). Our best case scenario is to be able to connect directly to MongoDB, without any connector or middle connection or software

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so if PowerBI doesn't support it already. The MongoDB BI Connector isn't installed in IBM Cloud Databases for MongoDB.